# Bootstrap 3.x: How to horizontal align, evenly space inlined radio buttons?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My WebApp generates the following code:

```
<div class="form-group" id="birthDate_field">   
    <label class="control-label sr-only" for="birthDate">Birth date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></span></span>
        <input type="date" id="birthDate" name="birthDate" value="" class="form-control form-control input-lg" placeholder="Birth date">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="gender_field">
    <div class="input-group">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label class="radio-inline" for="gender_female">
            <input type="radio" id="gender_female" name="gender" value="female" required="true">
            <i class="fa fa-female"></i> Female
        </label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label class="radio-inline" for="gender_male">
            <input type="radio" id="gender_male" name="gender" value="male" required="true">
            <i class="fa fa-male"></i> Male
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="email_field">
    <label class="control-label sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" class="form-control form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</div>
```

Which results in the following output:
[image]

However, there I am horizontally aligning the buttons using blank spaces which is a terrible approach. How do you do this in Bootstrap 3.x? Also would be great wrapping the radio buttons in a box that matches in dimensions the ones on top and bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the demo below, you will see that the icons align perfectly.
Please check your code to remove additional css which might be affecting the layout.

If in case, you cannot remove the additional css.

Use **display:flex and then align-items: center || baseline** on #gender-field's *input-group*

Hope this helps.

```css
#gender_field .input-group > label:first-child{
  padding: 0 30px 0 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<div class="form-group" id="birthDate_field">   
    <label class="control-label sr-only" for="birthDate">Birth date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></span></span>
        <input type="date" id="birthDate" name="birthDate" value="" class="form-control form-control input-lg" placeholder="Birth date">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="gender_field">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="radio-inline" for="gender_female">
            <input type="radio" id="gender_female" name="gender" value="female" required="true">
            <i class="fa fa-female"></i> Female
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline" for="gender_male">
            <input type="radio" id="gender_male" name="gender" value="male" required="true">
            <i class="fa fa-male"></i> Male
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="email_field">
    <label class="control-label sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" class="form-control form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! it is cool to have the icon and the radio button vertically aligned too .. I didn't know why was happening thanks! but my OP is more about horizontally aligning the radios in order to remove the blank `&nbsp;` spaces otherwise they appear  shifted to the left.

Comment: @SkyWalker hope this helps. Let me know if you want any changes.

Comment: you are not answering my OP you picked a different issue :)

Comment: @SkyWalker simple padding should do the job. I edited the snippet. Please check

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.gender{
   display : inline-block;
   width : 42%;
   padding : 5px;
   margin-right : 5%;
}
```

html

```
 <div class="form-group" id="birthDate_field">   
     <label class="control-label sr-only" for="birthDate">Birth date</label>
         <div class="input-group">
             <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></span></span>
             <input type="date" id="birthDate" name="birthDate" value="" class="form-control form-control input-lg" placeholder="Birth date">
         </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group" id="gender_field">
     <div class="input-group">

    <span class="gender">

         <label class="radio-inline" for="gender_female">
             <input type="radio" id="gender_female" name="gender" value="female" required="true">
             <i class="fa fa-female"></i> Female
         </label>

    </span>
    <span class="gender">

         <label class="radio-inline" for="gender_male">
             <input type="radio" id="gender_male" name="gender" value="male" required="true">
             <i class="fa fa-male"></i> Male
         </label>

    </span>

     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group" id="email_field">
     <label class="control-label sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="input-group">
             <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
             <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" class="form-control form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
 </div>
```